# Player controlled JPanel object getting stuck in certain corners of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, keyevent

I'm currently trying to make a java based platformer as a trial-by-fire way of teaching myself Java Swing. I currently have a JPanel in a JFrame and it is controlled by w-a-s-d. I'm currently coding in notepad and using the command line to run and keep watch on the script. (I know, no IDE is dumb, just couldn't be bothered right now)

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import javax.swing.*;  
public class PanelExample {
        private int dx;
    private int dy;
    private static javax.swing.Timer t;
    boolean x1 = false;
    boolean x2 = false;
    boolean y1 = false;
    boolean y2 = false;
        PanelExample()  {  
            JFrame f= new JFrame("Panel Example");  
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel p= new JPanel();
        p.setBounds(50,50,20,20);;
        p.setBackground(Color.red);
        f.add(p);
        f.setSize(700,400);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        new Timer(20, new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
                int bx = p.getLocation().x;
                int by = p.getLocation().y;
                if (x1 == true) {
                    p.setLocation(p.getLocation().x + 5, p.getLocation().y);
                } 
                else {
                    p.setLocation(p.getLocation().x, p.getLocation().y);
                }
                if (x2 == true) {
                    p.setLocation(p.getLocation().x - 5, p.getLocation().y);
                } 
                else {
                    p.setLocation(p.getLocation().x, p.getLocation().y);
                }
                if (y1 == true) {
                    p.setLocation(p.getLocation().x, p.getLocation().y + 5);
                } 
                else {
                    p.setLocation(p.getLocation().x, p.getLocation().y);
                }
                if (y2 == true) {
                    p.setLocation(p.getLocation().x, p.getLocation().y - 5);
                } 
                else {
                    p.setLocation(p.getLocation().x, p.getLocation().y);
                }
                if (bx < 0) {
                    p.setLocation(p.getLocation().x = 0, p.getLocation().y);
                }
                if (bx > 665) {
                    p.setLocation(p.getLocation().x = 665, p.getLocation().y);
                }
                if (by < 0) {
                    p.setLocation(p.getLocation().x, p.getLocation().y = 0);
                }
                if (by > 340) {
                    p.setLocation(p.getLocation().x, p.getLocation().y = 340);
                }
            System.out.println("X value: " + bx + " | Y value: " + by);
            }
        }).start();
        f.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                int ax = e.getKeyCode();
                int bx = p.getLocation().x;
                int by = p.getLocation().y;
                switch(ax)
                {
                    //the numbers on the cases corresond with w-a-s-d
                    //this is for the key s to go down
                    case 83:
                    if (by < 340){
                        y1 = true;
                    break;
                    }
                    //this is for the key d or right
                    case 68:
                    if (bx < 665){
                        x1 = true;
                    break;
                    //this is for the key w or up
                    }
                    case 87:
                    if (by > 0){
                        y2 = true;
                    break;
                    }
                    //this is for the key a or left
                    case 65:
                    if (bx > 0){
                        x2 = true;
                    break;
                    }
                }
                }
                @Override
                public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Key released code=" + e.getKeyCode());
                int ax = e.getKeyCode();
                switch(ax)
                {
                    case 83:
                        y1 = false;
                    break;
                    case 68:
                        x1 = false;
                    break;
                    case 87:
                        y2 = false;
                    break;
                    case 65:
                        x2 = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            });
        }  
        public static void main(String args[])  {  
            new PanelExample();  
        }
}
```

My issue is that when my object touches the  top or right walls, half the time it goes into the top left or top right corners, respectively. When this happens, for the top wall the key d stops working and for the right wall the key s stops working. I've tried to set if statements to stop all movement if it passes the borders but that doesn't help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *I know, no IDE is dumb* - I would disagree. When you learn without an IDE you learn Java/Swing. However, if you do use the IDE then use it to help compilation and debugging. Don't use it to generate your code. The generated code will not be portable/maintainable if you ever move to a different IDE. In any case your code does nothing for me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should NOT be using "magic numbers". For example:

```
case 83:
```

The API provide variables which make your code easier to read:

```
case KeyEvent.VK_S:
```

> My issue is that when my object touches the top or right walls

Not sure what is going on but I suspect you have a couple of issues:

1. you add the KeyListener to the wrong component. You are adding it to the frame, when you should be adding it to the content pane of the frame, since you add the red panel to the content pane. That is your red panel will never reach the top of the frame because the title bar is part of the frame. So when you do your test for 0, it needs to be relevant to the content pane of the frame.
2. I see hard coded values that mean nothing to me. What is 665? Is that meant to be the width? Don't hard code values. What if the user resizes the frame?

You can get the size dynamically with code like the following in your KeyListener:

```
Component c = (Component)e.getSource();
int width = c.getWidth();
```

However, if you make the above changes your code will stop working because KeyEvents are only generated for the component that has focus and your panel will not have focus because by default the panel is not focusable. The general advice in the forum is to use Key Bindings, not a KeyListener.

Check out [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for working example that incorporate all the above suggestions.

Comment: Should really be using Key Bindings instead of a KeyListener.